# Make correct version (branch) history in SVN (simulate delete revisions)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

As is well known, there is no way to delete revisions in SVN (*outside* SVN, you can delete the SVN database and revert to a backup version).

But *reverting* to a revision does not correct the version history: the "previous" version is from the branch you wish to discard, not the previous version your head revision was based on.

So I think that the way to proceed is to branch from the historical revision, then rename (move) the main branch, then rename (move) the historical revision into the (vacant) main branch. You will (I think?) wind up with a lot of identical create/delete intermediate versions, but that's less bad than having a lot of incorrect intermediate versions.

Is there a better way? Anyone care to walk me through the process?

Comment: Why do you want to remove historical revisions?

Comment: I don't want to remove them. I'm quite happy to have them recorded. I just don't want them to confuse the line of inheritance.  ABBA, ABBB, [ABCB,ACCB,ACCC],ABBB,ABBD